# Will the port become free when I stop the service of that instance?

Tags: service, port, assign, apache-tomee

I've this scenario where one software(older) uses port 8080. I'm trying to install another software of newer version where I would like it to use port 8080. So if I stop the service of the older version, but without uninstalling it, would I be able to assign 8080 to the newer software? Or do I need to take other actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **No**, you won't have to take further actions after the previous/old service is stopped. There is no need to deinstall it or force other things on it, *given* that the operating system terminates the process of that software correctly.

Just make sure it stays stopped, especially if the machine is rebooted.

Hope it helps.